# 2004 Ford Escape A/C Clutch working intermittently

Tags: ac

I'm having ac trouble with a 2004 ford escape v6 2wd. The air stopped working, so I had all the components, minus the evaporator, replaced and it worked like a charm. Then after a few months, the air stopped working and just blows hot air. I topped off the engine coolant and oil, and then it worked again...for 2 days. Then I found a busted vacuum line, fixed that and the air started working again...for 2 days. Then I replaced the ac clutch relay and the air worked again...for 1 day. I'm pretty sure at this point that there is an issue with a sensor that is keeping the ac clutch from engaging, but I don't know if I'm right, and even if I am, where to start with that.

Maybe also, and this is just a hunch, it may have something to do with the engine temp. The gauge isn't showing it as overheated, but I live in Florida and it's pretty hot right now and when I pop that hood, the engine bay is quite warm, so much that I usually keep the hood up for a few minutes before getting my hands dirty.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem ended up being a corroded wire to the AC clutch that would short out the connection randomly. Wire replaced. Problem solved.